# Confirming Paypal subscription with Codeigniter PayPal IPN Library

Tags: codeigniter, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using [PayPal IPN Library](https://github.com/orderly/codeigniter-paypal-ipn) to process a subscription payment. The Library logs to a database the IPN answer. The return URL is a "processing" page that checks at timed intervals for the "SUCCESS" status at ipn_log table. But I cant identify the current transaction row on this table. How can I confirm the payment has succeded? I can get the POST variables on the return URL, but none of them is registered on the database. Is there a variable that is returned by the IPN and also sent by POST to the return URL? Something like the transaction id? Maybe Im going the wrong way on this and there is another aproach to confirm the payment status.

Comment: Got it. The "custom" field added to the button form makes the trick. Saving it to the database is enough to keep track of the process.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it accepted so others having the same issue can find it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it. The "custom" field added to the button form makes the trick. Saving it to the database is enough to keep track of the process